Android intent filter not redirecting
The android intent filter does not launch the application
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="facix.fr" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="facix.fr" />
            </intent-filter>

The url im being redirected to is : https://facix.fr/success
How can I change my android manifest to make the redirection on my app working ?

You could add the path /success at the element data to catch the url
<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="facix.fr"
    android:path="/success" />

To test if your intent filter is properly configured you can use this command line.
I hope that will help you
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://facix.fr/success" your.package.name


The output for this command is
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://facix.fr/... pkg=com.example.facix_association_mobile } Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance. Status: ok LaunchState: UNKNOWN (0) Activity: com.example.facix_association_mobile/.MainActivity TotalTime: 0 WaitTime: 25 Complete
To be honest I don't understand what it means...

Here the analysis of the output:
Starting: Intent {...} ->  Indicates that the intent has been launched including the action android.intent.action.VIEW and the data: https://facix.fr/.
The warning ->  Indicates that the desired activity is already running and the intent has been passed to the existing instance for processing.
To better understand what is happening, you need to check how MainActivy manages the incoming intent.
I recommend logging the intent that MainActivity receives in the OnCreate() and OnNewIntent():
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     val intent = intent
     val action = intent.action
     val data = intent.data

     if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == action && data != null) {
         val url = data.toString()

         Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate(): Intent received with URL: $url")

     }


}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
         super.onNewIntent(intent)
         setIntent(intent) // Update the intent of MainActivity
    
         val data = intent.data
         if (data != null) {
             val url = data.toString()
    
             Log.d("MainActivity", "onNewIntent(): Intent received with URL: $url")
         }
    }

